# What is the difference between linear and plane polarization?

Tags: optics, definition, polarization

What is the difference between linear and plane polarization?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any difference. Linear polarization is the more modern and, in my view, better term.

The idea is that in a linearly polarised wave, if we represent the displacement vector at a point in the path of the wave by an arrow, then the arrow tip oscillates back and forth along a straight line. [For circularly polarised light, the tip of the displacement arrow goes round and round a circular path.]

The term 'Plane polarised' probably comes from  a linearly (!) polarised transverse wave in a rope *viewed along the rope*, so that the displacements all lie in one plane (a plane containing the rope itself). This is fine, but we don't call a circularly polarised wave 'cylindrically polarised' or 'helically polarised' do we?